# define a Generic, non serialising field in django rest serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This is just a layout of my serializer

```
class SerializerA(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field_a = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    field_b = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    field_c = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    field_d = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ("field_a", "field_b", "field_c", "field_d", "name", "designation")

    def get_field_a(self, obj):
        temp = TempUserModel.objects.get(pk=obj.uuid)
        field_a =  "some ORM query related to temp and TestModel model"
        return field_a

    def get_field_b(self, obj):
        temp = TempUserModel.objects.get(pk=obj.uuid)
        field_b =  "some ORM query related to temp and TestModel model"
        return field_b

    def get_field_c(self, obj):
        temp = TempUserModel.objects.get(pk=obj.uuid)
        field_c =  "some ORM query related to temp and TestModel model"
        return field_c
    
    def get_field_d(self, obj):
        field_d =  "some ORM query related to TestModel model"
        return field_d
```

Here `temp = TempuserModel.objects.get(pk=obj.uuid)` is same in 3 out of 4 of the  class methods. So is there any way that I can define it once somewhere in a serializer loop and use it without doing the same ORM query again and again?

Comment: Can you add your TestModel and TempUserModel models to your question? Seems like they are related in some way

Comment: lets take the case where both of them are not related directly

Comment: Its probably best to use a solution like a DAO layer in your project. Basically you override the manager of your model and make the query into-it. And than call the new implemented Method on your serializer.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models